# UI and Local Storage binding together

Tags: html, mvvm, knockout.js, local-storage

Can someone tell me if we can bind localStorage objects to the ui using Knockout.js or some other javascript framework?

What I want is - as the user loads up the page he gets the latest version of data from the local storage *(Using some framework)* and then I keep polling my service to see if there is any change in the data. If there is change I will update the local storage with the fresh data and make the ui update automatically *(Using some framework)*.

This complete flow is required to be done with minimum amount of code.

This might be too early to post since I have not researched much my self about how to go about it. Any help or redesign in terms of architecture is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest writing some code that checks if there is new data from your ajax service. If so, grab it, store it in a model which is in your viewmodel already bound to your UI. Also, save that model to localStorage.

If the data is not new, grab it from localStorage, put it in your model (that is in your viewmodel), and you are done.

Comment: thanks, I have already done this. I was thinking of using a framework/plugin for the same.